# Putting more chasis fans than the MotherBoard supports

Tags: cooling

My MB got only one chasis fan, sucking air inside. My friend told me that it's bad and that I gotta have another one. However, my MB only have one chasis fan connection , and the other is for a CPU fan I already have. So it should be enough, right? No, my friend says that I still gotta have another fan taking the sucked air out in order to have a normal air flow inside my computer, so it may live longer. So he say I need to buy a devider to the chasis fan connection.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the [su]. Could you edit your question a bit so it is clearly visible what you are asking?  Is your question "should I add another fan to the chassis?" Also please be more specific about your chassis and possibly MB/CPU – give us their types.

Comment: How many fans does your PC have? Do you just have one fan pulling air in? Is there not another fan pulling air out the back?

Comment: miroxlav- Tomorrow morning I'll check for the MB model, I have it in my laptop , it's a simple Asus one.
My question is - should I add another fan to the chassis when there is only one MB chasis fan connection?
DrZoo- you got it right.

Comment: You don't necessarily need more than one case fan.  Most generic cases have only one.

Comment: So the mb we're talking about is Asus p5g41c-m lx. A friend told me it's a quite simple one, btw it have 2 ddr 2 ram slots and 2 ddr 3 ram slots if it means you something.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of case fans available that plug into an unused disk drive power connector so you don't need to run them off the motherboard.

Comment: but is it nesscery?

Comment: You should have at least a one fan pulling in, and one pushing out. If you don't have something pulling it out, the heat will build up in the case. Depending on your case design, you could also have a fan that pulls air out from the top of the case, rather than one that pushes it out the back.

Comment: What you need at a minimum is one fan, pushing the air out. If your fan can push it out, enough air will come in.

Comment: @RoieShalom The more fans the cooler it runs and the longer it lasts.

Comment: My case don't have cooling openings on top. When I look at my case now, it's kind of a problem to install another fan also from the reason the air sirculation in my case can never be perfect. Lets call the back of case, where enery plugs in and all the wirings, side A. The side of the case where mb sits is side B, side C is the opposite side and D is the front where the on and reset buttons are. A 120 mm fan pulls air inside from side A. If I want to add fan (if most of you here will tell that I should because oppnions here are diffrent), I have two options, both bad, i think:

Comment: Option 1- Adding a fan at side D- there are no cooling oppenings in side D so actually the air won't have a chance to go out.
Option 2- Adding one big fan at side C that take air out, there are holes there for air to go out. But then I think what happen is- fan at side A sucks air in and then, even before the air had chance to observe system heat, the fan at side C will take the air out.

I'm confused by your answers as they are very opposite, my specs:
core2duo, 2 gb ram memory ddr3, radeon r7 200 series.
sums of fans in my system: 1chasis fan, 1cpu fan, 1 gpu fan.

Comment: If the 120 mm fan you have is actually pulling air in, I would suggest that you turn it around to have it exhaust air from the case.

Comment: @RoieShalom: A fan creates a difference in pressure between the inside and outside of the case.  Air will move whether it is being pulled or pushed, and either way, warmer air inside the case will be replaced by cooler air from outside.  The only real difference the fan's direction makes is if you blow air into the case and can aim it at a heat source, it will be a little more efficient at transferring heat from that source.  As long as the temperature readings are well within the specified operating ranges, you're accomplishing what needs to be done.